# How can I create some view over UIKeyBoard?

Tags: iphone, uikeyboard

I fill information then tap "Done" button for doing some process and show loading view for waiting.

I need loading view is over every view, but How can I do?

Thanks for adviser.

Here is my image (I'm new in here, so I can't post image)
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?62e2584aea.png

Answer (score 1):

You should make your keyboard disappear from the screen as soon as user taps on done button.
call this method

`[myTextField resignFirstResponder]`

when you start loading

Answer (score 1):

this is the best answer for your question
[textField setInputAccessoryView:inputAccessoryView];

Answer (score 0):

Did you *observe* the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` notifications? You can update the view elements in the handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the loading HUDView  ro whatever you are using for the purpose on the application's keywindow.
as
`[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:loadingView];`

ALso resigning the responder while the `loadingview` is displayed is really a very important thing you should do.

`[myTextField resignFirstResponder]`